# Button not work

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product

**Can u check my code please, ty 
when i press the button nothing happens**

**I think error in "actions"**

```
public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
           return $meta['general'] = [
                'children' => [
                    'products' => [
                        'arguments' => [
                            'data' => [
                                'config' => [
                                    'component' => 'Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/components/container-configurable-handler',
                                    'formElement' => 'container',
                                    'componentType' => 'container',
                                    'label' => __('Product list is empty')
                                    ),
                                    'template' => 'ui/form/components/complex',
                                    'createConfigurableButton' => 'ns = ${ $.ns }, index = add_product_button',
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                        'children' => [
                            'add_product_button' => [
                                'arguments' => [
                                    'data' => [
                                        'config' => [
                                            'formElement' => 'container',
                                            'componentType' => 'container',
                                            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/button',
                                            'actions' => [
                                                [
                                                    'targetName' => "product_product_form",
                                                    'actionName' => "add",

                                                ]
                                            ],
                                            'title' => __('Add Product'),
                                            'sortOrder' => 20,
                                        ],
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                    ],
                ];
```

Comment: Can you add some more clarity? What is the button suppose to do? Where is the button?

Comment: @MorganSmith ofc, ty for answer
this button should do the same thing Magento_Admin/Catalog/Product - > Add Product -> Related Products, Up-Sells, and Cross-Sells  (form name product_product_form | listing vendor_product_product_listing
https://ibb.co/hgPYSLL
but if u know how to make redirect to another link its good to
(example link admin/product/product/new/key/8f9580f0148a244219ece5deff944e162513c931d7c049ea8a456008112a69/

Comment: thanks for responding, i'd put this in your question so that other people can see it too. let me take a look at it